# Stored Procedure in .NET Core with CosmosDB gives error 500

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

So I am trying to create a stored procedure for a prototype web application.
My class/document name is "Plan" and it has a *Description* property and an *OrderingNumber* property as *int* -- the actual functions of these aren't exactly important to the issue, so let's leave that out.

The database is called "PlanDB" and the collection I wish to execute the stored procedure on is called "Plans", where I, of course, have also saved the stored procedure.

This is the function from my C# app:

**PlanService.cs**

```
    public async Task SwapOrderingNumbers(string id1, string id2)
    {
        try
        {
            await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<bool>(UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("PlanDB", "Plans", "swapOrderNumberSproc"), id1, id2);
        }
        catch (DocumentClientException de)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I have the parameters id1 and id2 which I wish to use in the execution of said stored procedure -- ideally, it should swap around the *OrderingNumber* of the 2 *Plans*.

**swapOrderNumberSproc**

```
    // Stored procedure for swapping ordering numbers
    //  @param planId1 - Plan 1's ID 
    //  @param planId2 - Plan 2's ID 

var swapOrderNumberSproc = {
id: "swapOrderNumberSproc",
serverScript: function (planId1, planId2) {
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var response = context.getResponse();

    var plan1Document, plan2Document;

    // query for Plans
    var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM Plans a where a.id  = "' + planId1 + '"';
    var accept = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, {},
        function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
            if (err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);

            if (documents.length != 1) throw "Unable to find both names";
            plan1Document = documents[0];

            var filterQuery2 = 'SELECT * FROM Plans a where a.id = "' + planId2 + '"';
            var accept2 = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery2, {},
                function (err2, documents2, responseOptions2) {
                    if (err2) throw new Error("Error" + err2.message);
                    if (documents2.length != 1) throw "Unable to find both names";
                    plan2Document = documents2[0];
                    swapOrder(plan1Document, plan2Document);
                    return;
                });
            if (!accept2) throw "Unable to read Plan details, abort ";
        });

    if (!accept) throw "Unable to read Plan details, abort ";

    // swap the two Plans’ OrderingNumbers
    function swapOrder(plan1, plan2) {
        var plan1NumberSave = plan1.OrderingNumber;
        plan1.OrderingNumber = plan2.OrderingNumber;
        plan2.OrderingNumber = plan1NumberSave;

        var accept = collection.replaceDocument(plan1._self, plan1,
            function (err, docReplaced) {
                if (err) throw "Unable to update Plan 1, abort ";

                var accept2 = collection.replaceDocument(plan2._self, plan2,
                    function (err2, docReplaced2) {
                        if (err) throw "Unable to update Plan 2, abort"
                    });

                if (!accept2) throw "Unable to update Plan 2, abort";
            });

        if (!accept) throw "Unable to update Plan 1, abort";
    }
}
```

The *SwapOrderingNumbers()* from C# is called via POST at the endpoint "/swapnumbers" in my controller:

**PlansController**

```
    [Route("swapnumbers")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task SwapOrderingNumbers()
    {
        await activityService.SwapOrderingNumbers("ca35e414-f1b8-49dc-89e7-61e2e100d14a", "dd4a8298-55b8-425b-b16b-f73229399107");

    }
```

For now, the IDs given as parameters are hardcoded to simplify.

Whenever I try to execute the stored procedure through the POST, it returns an error 500. What am I doing wrong?

**EDITS**

**Trace**

```
    Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BadRequestException: Message: {"Errors":
    ["Encountered exception while compiling Javascript. Exception = 
    SyntaxError: Syntax error\r\nSource information: line: 5, column: 1, 
    source line:\r\nvar swapOrderNumberSproc = {"]}
    ActivityId: bf1bacba-0375-4a51-9c94-07c89dfb4868, Request URI: 
    /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbServer19/partitions/a4cb495f-38c8-11e6-
    8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/
    at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportClient.ThrowIfFailed(String 
    resourceAddress, StoreResponse storeResponse, Uri physicalAddress, Guid 
    activityId)
    at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RntbdTransportClient.
    <InvokeStoreAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
```

**The part I removed from the stored procedure**

```
    var swapOrderNumberSproc = {
    id: "swapOrderNumberSproc",
    serverScript:
```

**Replaced with**

```
    function swapOrderNumberSproc(activityId1, activityId2) {
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the response from the SPROC call or actually checking what the Exception is?

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace? Is your collection Partitioned?

Comment: I've added the trace in the bottom of original post. Collection is not partitioned.

Comment: I removed the issue which was pointed out in the exception in line 5 -- will post exactly what part in the original post -- and the values now swap around as wanted. However, it still returns an error 500 upon posting.

Comment: Sorry to spam the comments -- quite new at this, and forgot to tag. @MatiasQuaranta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your SP script should be starting with `function swapOrderNumberSproc (planId1, planId2){`.

```
function swapOrderNumberSproc(planId1, planId2) {
var context = getContext();
var collection = context.getCollection();
var response = context.getResponse();

var plan1Document, plan2Document;

// query for Plans
var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM Plans a where a.id  = "' + planId1 + '"';
var accept = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, {},
    function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
        if (err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);

        if (documents.length != 1) throw "Unable to find both names";
        plan1Document = documents[0];

        var filterQuery2 = 'SELECT * FROM Plans a where a.id = "' + planId2 + '"';
        var accept2 = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery2, {},
            function (err2, documents2, responseOptions2) {
                if (err2) throw new Error("Error" + err2.message);
                if (documents2.length != 1) throw "Unable to find both names";
                plan2Document = documents2[0];
                swapOrder(plan1Document, plan2Document);
                response.setBody(true);
            });
        if (!accept2) throw "Unable to read Plan details, abort ";
    });

if (!accept) throw "Unable to read Plan details, abort ";

// swap the two Plans’ OrderingNumbers
function swapOrder(plan1, plan2) {
    var plan1NumberSave = plan1.OrderingNumber;
    plan1.OrderingNumber = plan2.OrderingNumber;
    plan2.OrderingNumber = plan1NumberSave;

    var accept = collection.replaceDocument(plan1._self, plan1,
        function (err, docReplaced) {
            if (err) throw "Unable to update Plan 1, abort ";

            var accept2 = collection.replaceDocument(plan2._self, plan2,
                function (err2, docReplaced2) {
                    if (err) throw "Unable to update Plan 2, abort"
                });

            if (!accept2) throw "Unable to update Plan 2, abort";
        });

    if (!accept) throw "Unable to update Plan 1, abort";
}
}
```

Also, you are not returning a `bool` at any point, you have to send the value in the `response`. I changed your `return;` to `response.setBody(true);`.

After that refactor, I was able to run it from C# without the compiling errors and returning a `bool`.

Comment: Thank you for this! After implementing your changes, I now get a 200 OK upon calling the stored procedure.